# Hide sibling boxes animation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'd like to animate some javascript here, but can't find a good solution. What i'm trying to do is :
- When you click on a box, all the other boxes disapear one by one. 
- If the box is let's say last, then it would be coming from last to first bloc, sliding to the left and then next line as the boxes disapear

[image: The boxes]

Right now, i've made some simple jquery but they all disapear at the same time, so it's like ultra weird! But i can't figure out how to animate this correctly. My code looks like this right now :

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 border border-default py-5 team-box">

    <h4 class="px-5">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>

    <a href="#" class="button-link px-5">
        Click Here
        <span class="btn-inner--icon">
            <img
            src="arrow-right-black.svg"
            alt="arrow-right-black"
            />
        </span>
    </a>

</div>
```

```
$(".team-box").on("click", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings().hide();
    });
```

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first()` to get first siblings

```
$(".team-box").on("click", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var first = $(this).siblings('.team-box').first();
        $(first).hide();
    });
```

```js
$(".team-box").on("click", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var first = $(this).siblings('.team-box').first();
        $(first).hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 border border-default py-5 team-box">

    <h4 class="px-5">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>

    <a href="#" class="button-link px-5">
        Click Here
        <span class="btn-inner--icon">
            <img
            src="arrow-right-black.svg"
            alt="arrow-right-black"
            />
        </span>
    </a>

</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 border border-default py-5 team-box">

    <h4 class="px-5">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>

    <a href="#" class="button-link px-5">
        Click Here
        <span class="btn-inner--icon">
            <img
            src="arrow-right-black.svg"
            alt="arrow-right-black"
            />
        </span>
    </a>

</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 border border-default py-5 team-box">

    <h4 class="px-5">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>

    <a href="#" class="button-link px-5">
        Click Here
        <span class="btn-inner--icon">
            <img
            src="arrow-right-black.svg"
            alt="arrow-right-black"
            />
        </span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey Hien, Thanks for the answer. The ```first()``` takes the first ```.team-box```, but it's not what i'm trying to do! I'd like the others that i haven't clicked to disappear one by one

Comment: Do you want to click one box and other box will sequence hidden?

Comment: Yes exactly! That how i should've written it the first time